# Proxy requests to backend using h2c

Tags: haproxy, http2

Re-asking [the question from HA-Proxy discourse site](https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/incorrect-scheme-set-while-proxying-to-a-http-2-cleartext-h2c-backend/3618) here in the hopes of getting more eyes on it.

I am using HA-Proxy version 1.9.4 2019/02/06 for proxying HTTP traffic to a h2c backend. I am however seeing HA-Proxy set the :scheme to `https` (and from as far as I can tell uses SSL in the request) when proxying the request. When I hit the backend directly, the :scheme is set to `http` and the request is non-SSL as expected. I have verified this HA-Proxy behavior using wireshark.

Any suggestions on what I should change in my configuration so that I can set to make sure that the :scheme gets set to `http` while proxying the request to the backend?

I am using curl 7.54.0 to make requests:
$ curl http://localhost:9090
where HA-Proxy is listening on port 9090.

My HA-Proxy config file:

```
global
   maxconn 4096
   daemon

defaults
   log   global
   option http-use-htx
   timeout connect 60s
   timeout client 60s
   timeout server 60s

frontend waiter
    mode http
    bind *:9090
    default_backend local_node

backend local_node
    mode http
    server localhost localhost:8080 proto h2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was reported as an [issue in haproxy github](https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/issues/77) and has been [fixed in version 2.0](https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/issues/77#issuecomment-502352482).

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported yet. The `client=>haproxy` connection can be HTTP/2, the `haproxy=>server` connection cannot.

https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.9/configuration.html#1.1

> HTTP/2 is only supported for incoming connections, not on connections
>   going to servers.

Comment: I think that documentation is in need of updating as the 1.9 announcement stated that end to end HTTP/2 was now supported: https://www.haproxy.com/blog/haproxy-1-9-has-arrived/

Comment: Alright, the doc is outdated. Your configuration is straight from the announcement, that should have worked.

Comment: Try ``haproxy -vv`` and check that alpn and/or h2 were compiled. Try enabling HTTP/2 on the frontend too, maybe it needs to be end to end.

Comment: Well my reading of the OPs question is that it is working, it’s just providing the original scheme rather than the scheme used for the last leg of the connection. OP doesn’t state if this causes the backend to fail to answer the request or if it’s just not what he expected. Either way this sounds like a bug to me if they are truly separate connections chained together, though perhaps a helpful bug, as long as the backend copes with it as it tells that this connection was originally over HTTPS which is probably more important to know than the last connection (e.g. to return HTTPS resources).

Comment: @BarryPollard In my scenario, the backend is expecting http and it fails if the request is using SSL (which it is). The configuration expects the request and the sceheme to be non-SSL.

Comment: Have you tried using “proto h2c”? Maybe it’s a typo in the HAProxy announcement.

Comment: h2c is not a valid option for backend proto: `parsing [haproxy.cfg:20] : 'server localhost' : 'proto' :  unknown MUX protocol 'h2c'`

Answer (score 0):

Just add [`proto h2`](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.0/configuration.html#5.1-proto) to the server definition.

Cite from [example](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/haproxy-1-9-has-arrived/#file-blog20181219-04-cfg):

```
server server1 192.168.1.13:80 proto h2
```

It's an experimental feature of haproxy-1.9, you must enable `option http-use-htx` to use it.

`option http-use-htx` is enabled by default since haproxy-2.0-dev3.